# setImageResource to an array of drawables throws nullpointer exception

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_orbital);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    Integer[] orbitalBodies = {R.drawable.dres, R.drawable.duna, R.drawable.eeloo, R.drawable.eve, R.drawable.jool, R.drawable.kerbin, R.drawable.kerbol, R.drawable.moho};
    int planetId = i.getExtras().getInt("intOrbitalId");
    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    img.setImageResource(orbitalBodies[planetId]); //this throws nullpointerexception
}
```

In debug I was able to confirm that orbitalBodies[planetId] returns the correct integer value for the drawables. I can't get past this little problem

Comment: It would appear that `img` is null.

Comment: Verify that R.id.image (ImageView) present inside the view_orbital layout.

Comment: Mike M nailed it. I was setting img to an object that didn't exist in the layout file. Never in my life did I think it would compile with that error, so I never thought to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use an `int` array in the place of an `Integer` array

```
int[] orbitalBodies = {R.drawable.dres, R.drawable.duna, R.drawable.eeloo, R.drawable.eve, R.drawable.jool, R.drawable.kerbin, R.drawable.kerbol, R.drawable.moho};
int planetId = getIntent.getExtras().getInt("intOrbitalId");

if(planetId != null) {
    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    img.setImageResource(orbitalBodies[planetId]);
}
```

Because

```
public static final class drawable 
{
        public static final int ic_launcher=0x7f020000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way...

```
img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(orbitalBodies[planetId]));
```

Comment: Any reason why this should work? (Your answer appeared in the low quality review queue)